# Matlab crashed when I call mexCallMATLAB(1,a,1,b,"transpose")

Tags: matlab, mex

I want to create a new sparse matrix and pass the value of the input sparse matrix to it, and then call Matlab to get its transpose. The code crashed, can you give me some suggestions?

```
extern void mexFunction(int iNbOut, mxArray *pmxOut[],
        int iNbIn, const mxArray *pmxIn[])
{

    mxArray *A, *B;
    double *d,*p,*pin,*out;
    mwSize m,n,nzmax;
    mwIndex *ir, *jc;

 // get the information of input sparse matrix
    m = mxGetM(pmxIn[0]);
    n = mxGetN(pmxIn[0]);
    nzmax = mxGetNzmax(pmxIn[0]);

    ir = mxGetIr(pmxIn[0]);
    jc = mxGetJc(pmxIn[0]);
    pin = mxGetPr(pmxIn[0]);

  // create a new sparse matrix and pass the input matrix to it
    A = mxCreateSparse(m, n, nzmax, mxREAL);
    mxSetIr(A, ir);
    mxSetJc(A, jc);
    mxSetPr(A, pin);
    d = mxGetPr(A);

    B = mxCreateSparse(m, n, nzmax, mxREAL);
// get the transpose of A by call matlab
    mexCallMATLAB(1, &B, 1, &A, "transpose");

    p = mxGetPr(B);

    pmxOut[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(1 , nzmax, mxSINGLE_CLASS,mxREAL); 
    out =  mxGetPr(pmxOut[0]);
    for(mwSize i = 0; i < nzmax; i++)
    {
        out[i] = p[i];
        mexPrintf("pmxOut = %f", out[i]);
    }


}
```